# How to convert originally byte type data received by string type to byte type?

Tags: python-3.6

Receives UTF-8 encoded binary data strings as text data. I want to convert the received text data into the original binary data string.

I thought it would be better to read the text data one byte at a time and convert it into binary data, but the first byte '\ xe3' of the text data becomes 'ã'.

Original data example is:

```py
>>> t = 'こんにちは'
>>> t.encode()
b'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
```

Received data is:

```py
>>> tc = '\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
>>> tc
'ã\x81\x93ã\x82\x93ã\x81«ã\x81¡ã\x81¯'
```

```py
>>> tc[0]
'ã'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the trick.

```py
In [1]: tc = '\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
```

Your `tc` is a `str` object, not a `bytes`. But what it represents is a series of bytes. So first, you encode it to latin1, which gives:

```py
In [2]: tc.encode('latin1')
Out[2]: b'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'
```

That is the same string, except it is a byte-string. (see the previx `b`) Now you can decode this byte-string into utf-8, thus

```py
In [3]: tc.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
Out[3]: こんにちは
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `decode()` function to decode the byte data, an example would be like

```
In [1]: t = 'こんにちは'

In [2]: t.encode()
Out[2]: b'\xe3\x81\x93\xe3\x82\x93\xe3\x81\xab\xe3\x81\xa1\xe3\x81\xaf'

In [3]: tc = t.encode()

In [4]: tc.decode()
Out[4]: 'こんにちは'
```

Hope it helps.